# SVG: Trigger a click event on animateTransform after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, smil

I would like to have my svg animation run when clicking an html button. I thought I could make that work by setting `begin="click` in my `animateTransform` and then trigger a click event on the `animateTransform` (or the svg element containing the `animateTransform`, I tried both) using js.
Any advice would be a great help.

```js
var needle = $('#needle'),
  tape = $('#tape'),
  btn = $('#muhBtn');

btn.on('click', function() {
  needle.click();
  tape.click();
});
```

```css
#tape {
  fill: #ED1C24;
}

#needle {
  fill: #8DC63F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" xmlns:i="&ns_ai;" xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;"
  xml:space="preserve">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" class="background"/>
    <path class="st0" id="tape" d="M182.7,100c0,45.7-37,82.7-82.7,82.7V17.3C145.7,17.3,182.7,54.3,182.7,100z">
      <animateTransform id="animateTape"
                          attributeName="transform"
                          attributeType="XML"
                          type="rotate"
                          from="0 100 100"
                          to="180 100 100"
                          dur="5s"
                          begin="click"
                          repeatCount="1"/>  
      </path>
    <path d="M200,100c0,55.2-44.8,100-100,100V0C155.2,0,200,44.8,200,100z" class="mask"/>
      <polygon class="st1" id="needle" points="96,100 104,100 104,192 100,200 96,192">
      <animateTransform id="animateNeedle"
                          attributeName="transform"
                          attributeType="XML"
                          type="rotate"
                          from="0 100 100"
                          to="180 100 100"
                          dur="5s"
                          begin="click"
                          repeatCount="1"/>
      </polygon>
    </svg>
<button class="btn btn-warning" id="muhBtn">Begin!</button>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to start the animations just do it directly via javascript and the beginElement method, no need for all that click event rigmarole. Note that I've changed the begin on the animation from click to indefinite to make it clearer what's happening.

```js
var needle = $('#animateNeedle'),
 tape = $('#animateTape');
 btn = $('#muhBtn');

btn.on('click', function(){
 needle[0].beginElement();
 tape[0].beginElement();
});
```

```css
#tape{
  fill:#ED1C24;
}

#needle{
  fill:#8DC63F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" xmlns:i="&ns_ai;" xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="200px" height="200px"
  viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve">
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" class="background"/>
<path class="st0" id="tape" d="M182.7,100c0,45.7-37,82.7-82.7,82.7V17.3C145.7,17.3,182.7,54.3,182.7,100z">
  <animateTransform id="animateTape"
                      attributeName="transform"
                      attributeType="XML"
                      type="rotate"
                      from="0 100 100"
                      to="180 100 100"
                      dur="5s"
                      begin="indefinite"
                      repeatCount="1"/>  
  </path>
<path d="M200,100c0,55.2-44.8,100-100,100V0C155.2,0,200,44.8,200,100z" class="mask"/>
  <polygon class="st1" id="needle" points="96,100 104,100 104,192 100,200 96,192">
  <animateTransform id="animateNeedle"
                      attributeName="transform"
                      attributeType="XML"
                      type="rotate"
                      from="0 100 100"
                      to="180 100 100"
                      dur="5s"
                      begin="indefinite"
                      repeatCount="1"/>
  </polygon>
</svg>
<button class="btn btn-warning" id="muhBtn">Begin!</button>
```

Comment: that's it, thanks! But, why do the vars containing the svg selectors need indexes?

Comment: Because they are raw DOM methods and not jquery functions. [0] unwraps the jquery wrapper.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the _indefinite_ part! Was going mad on how to stop the animation from auto-starting :)