# SVG animation cannot be triggered programmatically, without using an HTML button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg

I have the following piece of code, that animates an SVG circle on click:

```
<circle id = "middle" cx="235" cy="235" r="100" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="0.5" fill="#ffcc00"> <animate begin="click" attributeName="fill" to="yellow" dur="1s"/>
```

It works fine when the user clicks inside the circle, but I would like to trigger the animation programmatically.

I tried `$("#middle").click();`, but the animation doesn't occur, even though the click event is issued. (I have also set `$("#middle").click(function() {
    audio.play();
});` and the sound is played all right).

Is there a way to animate the SVG by simulating the user click (on the SVG), without using an HTML button?

Comment: try $("#middle").on('click', function(){}); make sure in document ready

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVG: Trigger a click event on animateTransform after clicking a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31856890/svg-trigger-a-click-event-on-animatetransform-after-clicking-a-button)

Comment: Thank you for suggesting $("#middle").on('click', function(){});, but my problem is that I don't know what to write inside the function, in order to animate the SVG. I don't want the animation to be triggered by a click on a button, but by a click on the SVG itself.

Comment: I meant "I don't want the animation to be triggered by a click on a button", and this is how my question differs from 'SVG: Trigger a click event on animateTransform after clicking a button'.

Comment: @CristinaFierbinteanu Click on the circle and trigger the animation via javascript is what you want? What element you want to trigger from is pretty othogonal to the basic concept of running beginElement.

Comment: @RobertLongson No, I just want to trigger the animation via javascript, as if the circle was clicked. It's part of a more complex project, where I want to play back the user's actions (or show the user a correct sequence of animations). But I still want the animation to occur when I click on the circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [beginElement](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#InterfaceElementTimeControl) if you want to start an animation programatically.

```html
<svg>
  <circle id = "middle" cx="50" cy="50" r="25" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="0.5" fill="#ffcc00">
  <animate id="a" begin="click" attributeName="fill" to="yellow" dur="1s"/>
</circle>
</svg>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('a').beginElement();">>Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Your answer was clearer before you edited it (when it used a button to trigger the animation). I'm sorry my question was confusing, but I'm happy I learned! The mistake in my program was that the animation had no id, and I tried to use beginElement() with the id of the circle m(__)m

Comment: I've rolled it back to the first version.