# How can I start all the animations at once?

Tags: animation, svg, transformation, smil

I would like to be able to click on the handle on this SVG and then for all the animations to start, instead of only restarting every time the page gets refreshed.

There are a few other things that I would like to know how to do which are not that important.

1. The handle: How would I make that rotate back -15 deg, for 1.5's then hold that position for 3's then have a 1,5's animation where it rotates back to 0 deg. totaling a 5's animation

   2. The Pour: If I was to make that a shorter rectangle, how could I get the bottom of the rectangle to stretch down when the tap opens, then when the tap closes the top part closest to the tap should stretch down into the beer becoming hidden. making it look more like the beer is falling out of the tap.

I tried using [SVG: Trigger a click event on animateTransform after clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31856890/svg-trigger-a-click-event-on-animatetransform-after-clicking-a-button) but i could not get it to start the animation.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="233.816px" height="643.371px" viewBox="0 0 233.816 643.371" enable-background="new 0 0 233.816 643.371"
     xml:space="preserve">
    <path id="pour" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#C06028" d="M134.793,600.695c0,2.761-2.239,5-5,5h-5c-2.761,0-5-2.239-5-5
        v-340c0-2.761,2.239-5,5-5h5c2.761,0,5,2.239,5,5V600.695z">
<animate id="#animatePour" dur="0.1s" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" begin="4.9" repeatCount="0" fill="freeze" />
</path>
<g id="beer-glass_1_">
    <g id="beer_1_">
    <linearGradient id="beer-fill" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
          <stop offset="100%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#C06028">
            <animate id="#animateBeer1"attributeName="offset" values="0;1" repeatCount="1" dur="5s" begin="0"/>
          </stop>
          <stop offset="100%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="#C06028">
            <animate id="#animateBeer2" attributeName="offset" values="0;1" repeatCount="1" dur="5s" begin="0"/>
          </stop>       
      </linearGradient>
        <path id="beer-fill" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="url(#beer-fill)" d="M80.068,383.621
            c-0.731,4.043,0.561,17.75-0.415,24.842c-2.13,15.49-0.908,28.531,0.895,36.818c2.295,10.549,5.457,21.016,6.568,31.691
            c2.496,23.989,4.08,48.079,5.804,72.144c1.403,19.584,2.343,39.203,3.899,58.773c0.143,1.793,3.068,4.441,5.066,4.832
            c10.412,2.041,20.926,4.717,31.436,4.861c19.596,0.268,39.221-0.885,58.813-1.842c4.91-0.24,9.746-1.992,14.617-3.043
            c2.994-0.645,4.346-2.301,4.535-5.545c1.4-24.098,3.053-48.18,4.475-72.277c1.855-31.391,4.037-62.657,11.771-93.394
            c1.838-7.306,3.26-29.661,1.873-44.111c-0.568-5.906-0.922-8.063-0.717-11.75L80.068,383.621z"/>       
        <g id="beer-bubbles">
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="108.337" cy="631.698" r="5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="3s"
                        dur="2s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite">
                            </circle>       
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="133.793" cy="630.698" r="4">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="2s"
                        dur="3s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite">
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="181.17" cy="636.198" r="4.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="5.5s"
                        dur="1s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite">
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="204.337" cy="622.622" r="5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="3.5s"
                        dur="1.5s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite">
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="164.003" cy="626.622" r="4">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="2s"
                        dur="3s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite">
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="122.293" cy="620.122" r="2.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="5s"
                        dur="1s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite">
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="187.17" cy="624.122" r="1.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="4s"
                        dur="1.5s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite">
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="149.837" cy="634.198" r="2.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="5s"
                        dur="2s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite">
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="104.837" cy="619.122" r="1.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="2s"
                        dur="3s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite">
                            </circle>
        </g>
    </g>
    <path id="glass-light" opacity="0.4" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M99.138,412.893
        c-7.283-0.969-7.33-0.976-8.471,6.327c-2.135,13.66,1.293,26.705,3.902,39.969c3.234,16.442,5.487,33.095,7.663,49.723
        c1.531,11.703,2.247,23.514,3.282,35.28c0.293,3.328,1.399,5.123,4.586,3.42c0-10.257,0.45-20.234-0.104-30.155
        c-0.844-15.104-1.839-30.24-3.801-45.228c-1.547-11.831-5.221-23.38-6.855-35.205C98.267,429.25,99.138,421.208,99.138,412.893z"/>
    <path id="glass_1_" opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M234.15,406.965
        c-0.014-0.075-2.215-51.691-2.229-51.76c-0.605-2.835-3.385-1.696-5-0.793c-0.01,0.156,2.971,52.208,2.963,52.364
        c-0.613,11.878,0.381,24.086-2.236,34.485c-7.735,30.736-9.917,62.003-11.771,93.394c-1.423,24.097-3.074,48.18-4.476,72.277
        c-0.188,3.244-1.54,4.9-4.534,5.545c-4.871,1.05-9.707,2.803-14.617,3.043c-19.592,0.957-39.218,2.109-58.813,1.841
        c-10.51-0.145-21.024-2.819-31.437-4.86c-1.998-0.391-4.923-3.039-5.066-4.833c-1.557-19.57-2.497-39.188-3.899-58.772
        c-1.724-24.065-3.307-48.154-5.804-72.145c-1.111-10.676-4.273-21.143-6.567-31.69c-2.504-11.511-2.756-25.218-0.936-37.101
        c0.124-0.809,0.32-52.052,0.463-52.843c-2.516-1.228-3.44-0.6-4.063,0.005c-0.246,0.239-1.166,52.796-1.186,52.916
        c-0.515,2.971-1.537,8.079-1.939,10.334c0,4,0,8,0,12c0.937,5.031,1.485,10.173,2.876,15.076
        c6.298,22.195,8.559,44.973,10.181,67.853c1.175,16.572,2.348,33.146,3.4,49.726c1.293,20.367,2.598,40.735,3.618,61.116
        c0.412,8.237,2.684,12.077,10.593,14.702c3.285,1.091,6.725,1.868,10.156,2.33c6.703,0.902,13.448,1.483,20.176,2.197
        c13.333,0,26.666,0,40,0c3.264-0.371,6.563-0.554,9.785-1.15c7.938-1.472,15.993-2.617,23.703-4.901
        c5.107-1.513,7.354-5.948,7.484-11.659c0.27-11.767,0.885-23.535,1.705-35.279c2.328-33.334,4.05-66.737,7.555-99.951
        c2.092-19.845,7.08-39.383,10.768-59.059c0-4.333,0-8.667,0-13C234.539,415.778,234.607,409.392,234.15,406.965z"/>
    <path id="foam" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M227.107,357.142c0.008-0.202,0.029-0.4,0.029-0.604
        c0-8.284-6.715-15-15-15c-1.994,0-3.894,0.397-5.634,1.104c-3.636-3.758-8.724-6.104-14.366-6.104c-2.441,0-4.77,0.459-6.933,1.26
        c-3.116-1.395-6.565-2.177-10.2-2.177c-5.556,0-10.686,1.814-14.836,4.88c-3.33-2.478-7.444-3.963-11.914-3.963
        c-6.477,0-12.217,3.092-15.872,7.865c-3.65-2.085-7.873-3.282-12.377-3.282c-4.183,0-8.122,1.032-11.586,2.848
        c-1.612-0.592-3.346-0.932-5.164-0.932c-5.568,0-10.416,3.041-13.004,7.545c-9.739,1.345-17.246,9.68-17.246,19.789
        c0,11.046,8.954,20,20,20c4.576,0,8.78-1.554,12.15-4.14c4.152,3.071,9.288,4.89,14.85,4.89c2.877,0,5.638-0.492,8.21-1.387
        c1.578,0.564,3.269,0.887,5.04,0.887c4.178,0,7.955-1.711,10.674-4.468c3.667,4.21,9.053,6.884,15.075,6.884
        c6.28,0,11.878-2.9,15.545-7.428c0.152,0.003,0.303,0.012,0.455,0.012c0.599,0,1.191-0.029,1.779-0.07
        c2.53,4.71,7.5,7.914,13.221,7.914c4.706,0,8.902-2.171,11.652-5.563c3.542,3.183,8.211,5.135,13.348,5.135
        c11.045,0,20-8.954,20-20C235.003,366.547,231.898,360.795,227.107,357.142z">
            <animateTransform id="animateFoam"
            attributeName="transform"
            type="translate"
            from="0 250"
            to="0 0"
            begin="0"
            dur="5s">
        </path>
</g>
<g id="tap">
    <path id="tap-handle" class="handle" fill="#2B2C2B" d="M123.077,164.857l-2.97-158.875c0-3.304,6.71-5.982,14.981-5.982
        c8.275,0,14.984,2.678,14.984,5.982l-2.996,160.327h-0.242c1.662,2.89,2.641,6.394,2.641,10.168
        c0,9.914-6.707,17.946-14.983,17.946c-8.273,0-14.982-8.034-14.982-17.946C119.509,172.044,120.853,167.988,123.077,164.857z">
           <animateTransform id="animateHandle"
            attributeName="transform"
            type="rotate"
            from="0 130 160"
            to="-15 130 160"
            begin="0"
            dur="5s">
        </path>     
    <path id="tap_1_" fill="#2B2C2B" d="M174,193.621h-21.575c0-9.914-8.051-17.947-17.979-17.947s-17.979,8.035-17.979,17.947H84.69
        l1.711-28.459c0-0.826-2.685-1.496-5.993-1.496c-3.311,0-5.993,0.67-5.993,1.496l1.711,28.459H47.348l-5.994-5.984v-4.787
        c0-3.963-2.685-7.178-5.993-7.178H17.378c-2.968,0-5.427,2.588-5.902,5.982H5.992c-3.31,0-5.993,2.678-5.992,5.982v47.858
        c0,3.305,2.685,5.981,5.992,5.981h5.483c0.478,3.396,2.937,5.983,5.903,5.983h17.98c3.31,0,5.991-3.215,5.991-7.183V233.7
        l5.993-5.982h38.854l29.595,43.978c1.898,2.707,8.933,1.063,15.711-3.678c6.779-4.738,10.735-10.771,8.838-13.479l-18.758-28.018
        l50.621-2.99c3.309,0,7.791-6.695,7.791-14.957C179.995,200.316,177.312,193.621,174,193.621z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can begin animations onclick events and use + to add additional time offsets. I've made some additional corrections below too so that everything starts off looking reasonable.

One thing making life difficult for you is that your id values contain - signs. They would normally be interpreted as the beginning of time offsets but they can be escaped as I've done below.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="233.816px" height="643.371px" viewBox="0 0 233.816 643.371" enable-background="new 0 0 233.816 643.371"
     xml:space="preserve">
    <path id="pour" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#C06028" d="M134.793,600.695c0,2.761-2.239,5-5,5h-5c-2.761,0-5-2.239-5-5
        v-340c0-2.761,2.239-5,5-5h5c2.761,0,5,2.239,5,5V600.695z" opacity="0">
      <set attributeName="opacity" to="1" begin="tap\-handle.click" repeatCount="0" fill="freeze" />
<animate id="animatePour" dur="0.1s" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" begin="tap\-handle.click + 4.9s" repeatCount="0" fill="freeze" />
</path>
<g id="beer-glass_1_">
    <g id="beer_1_">
    <linearGradient id="beer-fill-g" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#C06028">
            <animate id="#animateBeer1"attributeName="offset" values="0;1" repeatCount="1" dur="5s" begin="tap\-handle.click" fill="freeze"/>
          </stop>
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="#C06028">
            <animate id="#animateBeer2" attributeName="offset" values="0;1" repeatCount="1" dur="5s" begin="tap\-handle.click" fill="freeze"/>
          </stop>       
      </linearGradient>
        <path id="beer-fill" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="url(#beer-fill-g)" d="M80.068,383.621
            c-0.731,4.043,0.561,17.75-0.415,24.842c-2.13,15.49-0.908,28.531,0.895,36.818c2.295,10.549,5.457,21.016,6.568,31.691
            c2.496,23.989,4.08,48.079,5.804,72.144c1.403,19.584,2.343,39.203,3.899,58.773c0.143,1.793,3.068,4.441,5.066,4.832
            c10.412,2.041,20.926,4.717,31.436,4.861c19.596,0.268,39.221-0.885,58.813-1.842c4.91-0.24,9.746-1.992,14.617-3.043
            c2.994-0.645,4.346-2.301,4.535-5.545c1.4-24.098,3.053-48.18,4.475-72.277c1.855-31.391,4.037-62.657,11.771-93.394
            c1.838-7.306,3.26-29.661,1.873-44.111c-0.568-5.906-0.922-8.063-0.717-11.75L80.068,383.621z"/>       
        <g id="beer-bubbles">
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="108.337" cy="631.698" r="5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="tap\-handle.click + 3s"
                        dur="2s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>       
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="133.793" cy="630.698" r="4">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="tap\-handle.click + 2s"
                        dur="3s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="181.17" cy="636.198" r="4.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="tap\-handle.click + 5.5s"
                        dur="1s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="204.337" cy="622.622" r="5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="tap\-handle.click + 3.5s"
                        dur="1.5s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="164.003" cy="626.622" r="4">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="tap\-handle.click + 2s"
                        dur="3s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="122.293" cy="620.122" r="2.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="tap\-handle.click + 5s"
                        dur="1s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="187.17" cy="624.122" r="1.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="tap\-handle.click + 4s"
                        dur="1.5s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="149.837" cy="634.198" r="2.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="tap\-handle.click + 5s"
                        dur="2s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="104.837" cy="619.122" r="1.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="tap\-handle.click + 2s"
                        dur="3s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
        </g>
    </g>
    <path id="glass-light" opacity="0.4" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M99.138,412.893
        c-7.283-0.969-7.33-0.976-8.471,6.327c-2.135,13.66,1.293,26.705,3.902,39.969c3.234,16.442,5.487,33.095,7.663,49.723
        c1.531,11.703,2.247,23.514,3.282,35.28c0.293,3.328,1.399,5.123,4.586,3.42c0-10.257,0.45-20.234-0.104-30.155
        c-0.844-15.104-1.839-30.24-3.801-45.228c-1.547-11.831-5.221-23.38-6.855-35.205C98.267,429.25,99.138,421.208,99.138,412.893z"/>
    <path id="glass_1_" opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M234.15,406.965
        c-0.014-0.075-2.215-51.691-2.229-51.76c-0.605-2.835-3.385-1.696-5-0.793c-0.01,0.156,2.971,52.208,2.963,52.364
        c-0.613,11.878,0.381,24.086-2.236,34.485c-7.735,30.736-9.917,62.003-11.771,93.394c-1.423,24.097-3.074,48.18-4.476,72.277
        c-0.188,3.244-1.54,4.9-4.534,5.545c-4.871,1.05-9.707,2.803-14.617,3.043c-19.592,0.957-39.218,2.109-58.813,1.841
        c-10.51-0.145-21.024-2.819-31.437-4.86c-1.998-0.391-4.923-3.039-5.066-4.833c-1.557-19.57-2.497-39.188-3.899-58.772
        c-1.724-24.065-3.307-48.154-5.804-72.145c-1.111-10.676-4.273-21.143-6.567-31.69c-2.504-11.511-2.756-25.218-0.936-37.101
        c0.124-0.809,0.32-52.052,0.463-52.843c-2.516-1.228-3.44-0.6-4.063,0.005c-0.246,0.239-1.166,52.796-1.186,52.916
        c-0.515,2.971-1.537,8.079-1.939,10.334c0,4,0,8,0,12c0.937,5.031,1.485,10.173,2.876,15.076
        c6.298,22.195,8.559,44.973,10.181,67.853c1.175,16.572,2.348,33.146,3.4,49.726c1.293,20.367,2.598,40.735,3.618,61.116
        c0.412,8.237,2.684,12.077,10.593,14.702c3.285,1.091,6.725,1.868,10.156,2.33c6.703,0.902,13.448,1.483,20.176,2.197
        c13.333,0,26.666,0,40,0c3.264-0.371,6.563-0.554,9.785-1.15c7.938-1.472,15.993-2.617,23.703-4.901
        c5.107-1.513,7.354-5.948,7.484-11.659c0.27-11.767,0.885-23.535,1.705-35.279c2.328-33.334,4.05-66.737,7.555-99.951
        c2.092-19.845,7.08-39.383,10.768-59.059c0-4.333,0-8.667,0-13C234.539,415.778,234.607,409.392,234.15,406.965z"/>
    <path id="foam" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M227.107,357.142c0.008-0.202,0.029-0.4,0.029-0.604
        c0-8.284-6.715-15-15-15c-1.994,0-3.894,0.397-5.634,1.104c-3.636-3.758-8.724-6.104-14.366-6.104c-2.441,0-4.77,0.459-6.933,1.26
        c-3.116-1.395-6.565-2.177-10.2-2.177c-5.556,0-10.686,1.814-14.836,4.88c-3.33-2.478-7.444-3.963-11.914-3.963
        c-6.477,0-12.217,3.092-15.872,7.865c-3.65-2.085-7.873-3.282-12.377-3.282c-4.183,0-8.122,1.032-11.586,2.848
        c-1.612-0.592-3.346-0.932-5.164-0.932c-5.568,0-10.416,3.041-13.004,7.545c-9.739,1.345-17.246,9.68-17.246,19.789
        c0,11.046,8.954,20,20,20c4.576,0,8.78-1.554,12.15-4.14c4.152,3.071,9.288,4.89,14.85,4.89c2.877,0,5.638-0.492,8.21-1.387
        c1.578,0.564,3.269,0.887,5.04,0.887c4.178,0,7.955-1.711,10.674-4.468c3.667,4.21,9.053,6.884,15.075,6.884
        c6.28,0,11.878-2.9,15.545-7.428c0.152,0.003,0.303,0.012,0.455,0.012c0.599,0,1.191-0.029,1.779-0.07
        c2.53,4.71,7.5,7.914,13.221,7.914c4.706,0,8.902-2.171,11.652-5.563c3.542,3.183,8.211,5.135,13.348,5.135
        c11.045,0,20-8.954,20-20C235.003,366.547,231.898,360.795,227.107,357.142z" transform="translate(0, 250)">
            <animateTransform id="animateFoam"
            attributeName="transform"
            type="translate"
            from="0 250"
            to="0 0"
            begin="tap\-handle.click"
            dur="5s" fill="freeze"/>
        </path>
</g>
<g id="tap">
    <path id="tap-handle" class="handle" fill="#2B2C2B" d="M123.077,164.857l-2.97-158.875c0-3.304,6.71-5.982,14.981-5.982
        c8.275,0,14.984,2.678,14.984,5.982l-2.996,160.327h-0.242c1.662,2.89,2.641,6.394,2.641,10.168
        c0,9.914-6.707,17.946-14.983,17.946c-8.273,0-14.982-8.034-14.982-17.946C119.509,172.044,120.853,167.988,123.077,164.857z">
           <animateTransform id="animateHandle"
            attributeName="transform"
            type="rotate"
            from="0 130 160"
            to="-15 130 160"
            begin="tap\-handle.click"
            dur="5s"/>
        </path>     
    <path id="tap_1_" fill="#2B2C2B" d="M174,193.621h-21.575c0-9.914-8.051-17.947-17.979-17.947s-17.979,8.035-17.979,17.947H84.69
        l1.711-28.459c0-0.826-2.685-1.496-5.993-1.496c-3.311,0-5.993,0.67-5.993,1.496l1.711,28.459H47.348l-5.994-5.984v-4.787
        c0-3.963-2.685-7.178-5.993-7.178H17.378c-2.968,0-5.427,2.588-5.902,5.982H5.992c-3.31,0-5.993,2.678-5.992,5.982v47.858
        c0,3.305,2.685,5.981,5.992,5.981h5.483c0.478,3.396,2.937,5.983,5.903,5.983h17.98c3.31,0,5.991-3.215,5.991-7.183V233.7
        l5.993-5.982h38.854l29.595,43.978c1.898,2.707,8.933,1.063,15.711-3.678c6.779-4.738,10.735-10.771,8.838-13.479l-18.758-28.018
        l50.621-2.99c3.309,0,7.791-6.695,7.791-14.957C179.995,200.316,177.312,193.621,174,193.621z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Alternatively for browsers that can't handle SMIL escaping properly...

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="233.816px" height="643.371px" viewBox="0 0 233.816 643.371" enable-background="new 0 0 233.816 643.371"
     xml:space="preserve">
    <path id="pour" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#C06028" d="M134.793,600.695c0,2.761-2.239,5-5,5h-5c-2.761,0-5-2.239-5-5
        v-340c0-2.761,2.239-5,5-5h5c2.761,0,5,2.239,5,5V600.695z" opacity="0">
      <set attributeName="opacity" to="1" begin="tapHandle.click" repeatCount="0" fill="freeze" />
<animate id="animatePour" dur="0.1s" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" begin="tapHandle.click + 4.9s" repeatCount="0" fill="freeze" />
</path>
<g id="beer-glass_1_">
    <g id="beer_1_">
    <linearGradient id="beer-fill-g" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#C06028">
            <animate id="#animateBeer1"attributeName="offset" values="0;1" repeatCount="1" dur="5s" begin="tapHandle.click" fill="freeze"/>
          </stop>
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="#C06028">
            <animate id="#animateBeer2" attributeName="offset" values="0;1" repeatCount="1" dur="5s" begin="tapHandle.click" fill="freeze"/>
          </stop>       
      </linearGradient>
        <path id="beer-fill" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="url(#beer-fill-g)" d="M80.068,383.621
            c-0.731,4.043,0.561,17.75-0.415,24.842c-2.13,15.49-0.908,28.531,0.895,36.818c2.295,10.549,5.457,21.016,6.568,31.691
            c2.496,23.989,4.08,48.079,5.804,72.144c1.403,19.584,2.343,39.203,3.899,58.773c0.143,1.793,3.068,4.441,5.066,4.832
            c10.412,2.041,20.926,4.717,31.436,4.861c19.596,0.268,39.221-0.885,58.813-1.842c4.91-0.24,9.746-1.992,14.617-3.043
            c2.994-0.645,4.346-2.301,4.535-5.545c1.4-24.098,3.053-48.18,4.475-72.277c1.855-31.391,4.037-62.657,11.771-93.394
            c1.838-7.306,3.26-29.661,1.873-44.111c-0.568-5.906-0.922-8.063-0.717-11.75L80.068,383.621z"/>       
        <g id="beer-bubbles">
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="108.337" cy="631.698" r="5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="tapHandle.click + 3s"
                        dur="2s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>       
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="133.793" cy="630.698" r="4">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="tapHandle.click + 2s"
                        dur="3s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="181.17" cy="636.198" r="4.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="tapHandle.click + 5.5s"
                        dur="1s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="204.337" cy="622.622" r="5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="tapHandle.click + 3.5s"
                        dur="1.5s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="164.003" cy="626.622" r="4">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="tapHandle.click + 2s"
                        dur="3s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="122.293" cy="620.122" r="2.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="tapHandle.click + 5s"
                        dur="1s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="187.17" cy="624.122" r="1.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="tapHandle.click + 4s"
                        dur="1.5s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="149.837" cy="634.198" r="2.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="tapHandle.click + 5s"
                        dur="2s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="104.837" cy="619.122" r="1.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="tapHandle.click + 2s"
                        dur="3s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
        </g>
    </g>
    <path id="glass-light" opacity="0.4" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M99.138,412.893
        c-7.283-0.969-7.33-0.976-8.471,6.327c-2.135,13.66,1.293,26.705,3.902,39.969c3.234,16.442,5.487,33.095,7.663,49.723
        c1.531,11.703,2.247,23.514,3.282,35.28c0.293,3.328,1.399,5.123,4.586,3.42c0-10.257,0.45-20.234-0.104-30.155
        c-0.844-15.104-1.839-30.24-3.801-45.228c-1.547-11.831-5.221-23.38-6.855-35.205C98.267,429.25,99.138,421.208,99.138,412.893z"/>
    <path id="glass_1_" opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M234.15,406.965
        c-0.014-0.075-2.215-51.691-2.229-51.76c-0.605-2.835-3.385-1.696-5-0.793c-0.01,0.156,2.971,52.208,2.963,52.364
        c-0.613,11.878,0.381,24.086-2.236,34.485c-7.735,30.736-9.917,62.003-11.771,93.394c-1.423,24.097-3.074,48.18-4.476,72.277
        c-0.188,3.244-1.54,4.9-4.534,5.545c-4.871,1.05-9.707,2.803-14.617,3.043c-19.592,0.957-39.218,2.109-58.813,1.841
        c-10.51-0.145-21.024-2.819-31.437-4.86c-1.998-0.391-4.923-3.039-5.066-4.833c-1.557-19.57-2.497-39.188-3.899-58.772
        c-1.724-24.065-3.307-48.154-5.804-72.145c-1.111-10.676-4.273-21.143-6.567-31.69c-2.504-11.511-2.756-25.218-0.936-37.101
        c0.124-0.809,0.32-52.052,0.463-52.843c-2.516-1.228-3.44-0.6-4.063,0.005c-0.246,0.239-1.166,52.796-1.186,52.916
        c-0.515,2.971-1.537,8.079-1.939,10.334c0,4,0,8,0,12c0.937,5.031,1.485,10.173,2.876,15.076
        c6.298,22.195,8.559,44.973,10.181,67.853c1.175,16.572,2.348,33.146,3.4,49.726c1.293,20.367,2.598,40.735,3.618,61.116
        c0.412,8.237,2.684,12.077,10.593,14.702c3.285,1.091,6.725,1.868,10.156,2.33c6.703,0.902,13.448,1.483,20.176,2.197
        c13.333,0,26.666,0,40,0c3.264-0.371,6.563-0.554,9.785-1.15c7.938-1.472,15.993-2.617,23.703-4.901
        c5.107-1.513,7.354-5.948,7.484-11.659c0.27-11.767,0.885-23.535,1.705-35.279c2.328-33.334,4.05-66.737,7.555-99.951
        c2.092-19.845,7.08-39.383,10.768-59.059c0-4.333,0-8.667,0-13C234.539,415.778,234.607,409.392,234.15,406.965z"/>
    <path id="foam" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M227.107,357.142c0.008-0.202,0.029-0.4,0.029-0.604
        c0-8.284-6.715-15-15-15c-1.994,0-3.894,0.397-5.634,1.104c-3.636-3.758-8.724-6.104-14.366-6.104c-2.441,0-4.77,0.459-6.933,1.26
        c-3.116-1.395-6.565-2.177-10.2-2.177c-5.556,0-10.686,1.814-14.836,4.88c-3.33-2.478-7.444-3.963-11.914-3.963
        c-6.477,0-12.217,3.092-15.872,7.865c-3.65-2.085-7.873-3.282-12.377-3.282c-4.183,0-8.122,1.032-11.586,2.848
        c-1.612-0.592-3.346-0.932-5.164-0.932c-5.568,0-10.416,3.041-13.004,7.545c-9.739,1.345-17.246,9.68-17.246,19.789
        c0,11.046,8.954,20,20,20c4.576,0,8.78-1.554,12.15-4.14c4.152,3.071,9.288,4.89,14.85,4.89c2.877,0,5.638-0.492,8.21-1.387
        c1.578,0.564,3.269,0.887,5.04,0.887c4.178,0,7.955-1.711,10.674-4.468c3.667,4.21,9.053,6.884,15.075,6.884
        c6.28,0,11.878-2.9,15.545-7.428c0.152,0.003,0.303,0.012,0.455,0.012c0.599,0,1.191-0.029,1.779-0.07
        c2.53,4.71,7.5,7.914,13.221,7.914c4.706,0,8.902-2.171,11.652-5.563c3.542,3.183,8.211,5.135,13.348,5.135
        c11.045,0,20-8.954,20-20C235.003,366.547,231.898,360.795,227.107,357.142z" transform="translate(0, 250)">
            <animateTransform id="animateFoam"
            attributeName="transform"
            type="translate"
            from="0 250"
            to="0 0"
            begin="tapHandle.click"
            dur="5s" fill="freeze"/>
        </path>
</g>
<g id="tap">
    <path id="tapHandle" class="handle" fill="#2B2C2B" d="M123.077,164.857l-2.97-158.875c0-3.304,6.71-5.982,14.981-5.982
        c8.275,0,14.984,2.678,14.984,5.982l-2.996,160.327h-0.242c1.662,2.89,2.641,6.394,2.641,10.168
        c0,9.914-6.707,17.946-14.983,17.946c-8.273,0-14.982-8.034-14.982-17.946C119.509,172.044,120.853,167.988,123.077,164.857z">
           <animateTransform id="animateHandle"
            attributeName="transform"
            type="rotate"
            from="0 130 160"
            to="-15 130 160"
            begin="tapHandle.click"
            dur="5s"/>
        </path>     
    <path id="tap_1_" fill="#2B2C2B" d="M174,193.621h-21.575c0-9.914-8.051-17.947-17.979-17.947s-17.979,8.035-17.979,17.947H84.69
        l1.711-28.459c0-0.826-2.685-1.496-5.993-1.496c-3.311,0-5.993,0.67-5.993,1.496l1.711,28.459H47.348l-5.994-5.984v-4.787
        c0-3.963-2.685-7.178-5.993-7.178H17.378c-2.968,0-5.427,2.588-5.902,5.982H5.992c-3.31,0-5.993,2.678-5.992,5.982v47.858
        c0,3.305,2.685,5.981,5.992,5.981h5.483c0.478,3.396,2.937,5.983,5.903,5.983h17.98c3.31,0,5.991-3.215,5.991-7.183V233.7
        l5.993-5.982h38.854l29.595,43.978c1.898,2.707,8.933,1.063,15.711-3.678c6.779-4.738,10.735-10.771,8.838-13.479l-18.758-28.018
        l50.621-2.99c3.309,0,7.791-6.695,7.791-14.957C179.995,200.316,177.312,193.621,174,193.621z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: How would I stop all the bubbles so that they are not floating up in the air faster than the foam when the handle is re-clicked?

Comment: Looks like Chrome doesn't like the escaping trick. If you change the id, and all the references to it, to `taphandle`, it works.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Raise a Chrome bug then :-)

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I've added a Chrome compatible version.

Comment: For future reference, [the filed bug is here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=675362)

Comment: I just changed the id for the tap-handle to taphandle. And that made it work as expected. Its just a personal project for me to increase my knowledge. I'm not to worried about making it backwards compatible.
No new ideas on resetting the bubbles?. If it will be too difficult i will rather remove them.

Comment: @Dylan I think I've answered the main question, if you have follow up questions, best ask them separately.